# ¿Cómo puedo encontrar y detener la aplicación que está utilizando el puerto en Linux?

Tags: python, linux, networking

Estoy programando un agente `SNMP` utilizando una `Raspberry Pi`, con sistema operativo `Raspbian`, y `PySNMP`. No puedo utilizar el `puerto 161` (que es el puerto predeterminado para `SNMP`), cuando corro mi aplicación me marca como error que el puerto está siendo utilizado. ¿Cómo puedo encontrar y detener la aplicación que está utilizando el puerto?

Comment: Deberias ver que aplicación tiene ocupado el puerto y si puedes o no detenerla vete a la terminal y buscala con `sudo fuser -k 161/udp`. Puedes crear un simple script en bash para que busque mate cualquier proceso que esté usando el puerto.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ver qué proceso está usando cualquier puerto de distintas maneras desde la terminal. Por ejemplo, una de ellas es:

```
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep :161
```

Sin embargo, ten en cuenta que el puerto 161 **es un puerto privilegiado**, ya que está por debajo del 1024. Esto significa que, por medidas de seguridad, su uso está restringido a usuarios con los permisos suficientes.

Por ello, si ves que no hay ningún otro proceso usando el puerto 161, prueba a ejecutar el programa como superusuario, usando `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías instalar el comando `htop` que muestra una interfaz mediante la línea de comandos de todos los procesos y el consumo de tu máquina:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install htop
```

en el este [link](https://hipertextual.com/archivo/2010/03/comando-linux-htop-administra-interactivamente-los-procesos-del-sistema/) se da una pequeña descripción

Answer (score 0):

Workaround

Si hay algún demonio de snmp que está cogiendo el puerto que tu quieres, haz una búsqueda en todos los ficheros de configuración, y cámbiale el puerto original por uno libre. 
Así cuando arranques el tuyo, ya estará libre.  Eso o directamente saber qué soft está cogiéndolo, y desinstalándolo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría este comando:

> sudo kill -9 $(lsof -i:161)

Donde:

- **kill -9**: Mata el proceso sin que pueda ser bloqueado.
- **lsof -i:161**: Busca el proceso que está escuchando en el puerto 161.
- El **$()** obtiene el valor resultado del comando **lsof** en este caso, para pasárselo como argumento a **kill -9**